# Snap.svg text with textpath does not animate as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

I'm having an issue animating text using snap.svg. I'm moving text around an arc, from the bottom left of the arc to its apex. I'm using the standard Snap.animate functionality with its built-in setter function.

When I animate a random element (such as the circle I've included in the examples below), the animation behaves as expected. When I animate plain text it also behaves as expected. When I add a textpath attribute to that text, however, the animation functions differently in ways I don't understand.

This text animates as expected:

```
svg.text(0,200,'Regular Text').attr({'text-anchor': 'middle'});
```

Example (hover for animation): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJbmYW

Whereas this text stops short of its desired destination (also the top of the arc:

```
var path = 'M0 200 A 200 200, 0, 1, 1, 400 200';
svg.text(0,200,'Arced Text').attr({'text-anchor': 'middle',
                                   'textpath':path});
```

Example (hover for animation): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJqaVp

I suppose I don't understand what adding the textpath is doing to the text object, as it seems I should be able to animate/transform its x and y coordinates as I could before I added the path.

Any insight or suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to animate x,y for a textPath in this case I think (I may be wrong), as what does that mean in respect to a fluctuating line.

I think what you want is to animate the startOffset. Eg...

```
 Snap.animate(0, arc.getTotalLength()/2,
    function(val){

        var point = arc.getPointAtLength(val);
        circ.attr({cx: point.x,
                   cy: point.y});
        arcText.textPath.attr({ startOffset: val})

     },1000,mina.easeinout);
```

with this bit being the main change ...

```
arcText.textPath.attr({ startOffset: val})
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPGNWZ) (hover over)

Comment: Yes this seems correct, thank you. The documentation on textPath is so sparse/nonexistent. I do still question why you can't simply move the object via its x/y coordinates, or why doing so produces the odd behavior above, but this is surely the preferred method of moving text along a path.